# What happens when you put a +1/+1 counter on a planeswalker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Some commander decks have Planeswalker commanders.  What happens when you put a +1/+1 counter on one of them, such as with [Opal Palace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=opal%20palace)?

Comment: Know what happens to a toad when it's struck by lightning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-creature permanents can have +1/+1 counters on them, they just don't do anything until the permanent becomes a creature. Say you have a man land. If you animate it, then add +1/+1 counters to it, they stay on it even when it stops being a creature.

Also, cards like [Earthen Arms](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Earthen%20Arms) can put counters on any permanent. Its gatherer says:

> Any permanent can have a +1/+1 counter put on it. Those counters won’t have any effect unless that permanent is or becomes a creature.

Answer (score 1):

A +1/+1 Counter exist on the commander. It doesn't count as a loyalty counter, it doesn't increase the loyalty.

If by some facet the commander is turned into a creature, the +1/+1 counter would change its power and toughness.